# コマンドラインでパスワードの文字列を作るには？

Tags: linux, macos, unix

コマンドラインでパスワードの文字列を作成するコマンドはありますか？

CentOS, Ubuntu, MacOS などに標準でインストールされているコマンドで作成がしたいです。

Comment: パスワードを作成する、とはどういうことでしょうか。パスワードは、プログラム的にはただの文字列だと考えられます。作成したパスワードを管理してくれるツールが欲しい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: ツールではなく文字列が欲しいです。

Comment: 「文字列が欲しい」とわかるように質問のタイトルを編集しました

Comment: パスワードとして利用できるような、(第三者が予測できない)文字列を、コマンドラインから自動で生成したい、ということでしょうか。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

様々なコマンドあります。

/dev/urandomを使う方法

```
strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 30 | tr -d '\n'; echo
```

opensslコマンドで

```
openssl rand -base64 32
```

gpgコマンドで

```
gpg --gen-random --armor 1 30
```

pwgenが人間のために覚えやすいパスワードを作成します。

```
pwgen 30 1
```

mkpasswdで

```
mkpasswd
```

Comment: `date +%s` は例としては不適切かと。

Comment: ```echo -n "string"```は適切ですか

Comment: 言葉足らずでした。すみません。‘date +%s` だとランダム性が足りないのがよくないと思いました。ランダムかどうかは質問の要件には挙がってはいないのですが、念の為。

Comment: そうです、ランダム性が足りないです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

既に色々挙がっていますが、
mkpasswd
というのが標準で入っているかもしれません。
mkpasswdでググるなりすれば、使い方は調べられると思います。

Answer (score 0):

UbuntuやMac OSならpwgen、CentOSならmkpasswdがデフォルトであります。
（インストールすれば組み合わせ関係ないですけど・・・）

8文字のランダムな文字がほしい場合は
「mkpassword」か「pwgen 8 1」でいいと思います。

Comment: vagrant@precise64:~$ pwgen
The program 'pwgen' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
ubuntu precise64にデフォルトで入れないです。

Comment: sudo apt-get install pwgenでインストールしてみてください

Comment: デフォルトでありませんの事です。